# How to load all field values from multiple entities?

Tags: entities, database

I have an EFQ that finds the users whose field values match a given array of values:

```
  $users_query = new EntityFieldQuery();

  $users_query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'user')
    ->fieldCondition('field_my_field', 'value', $array_of_values);

  $users_query_result = $users_query->execute();
```

This will create a list of uid's but I need to know which uid goes with which value in the array.

Answer (score 1):

[EFQ](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) will return an entity stub, if you want the fully loaded entities, you can try something like:

```
// Build query
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'user');
$query->fieldCondition('field_my_field', 'value', $values);
// Execute for result
$result = $query->execute();
// If has data
if (!empty($result['user'])) {
  // Load users
  $accounts = entity_load('user', array_keys($result['user']));
  // If using devel
  // dpm($accounts);
}else{
  // No results
}
```

Comment: This is essentially what I ended up doing with user_load_multiple. How much of a performance hit is it to load entire users instead of just that field?

Comment: Loading the full user object is more performance intensive than loading a single field. Normally, you'd use EFQ if you want the actual entities, if you just want some basic field data, a simple db_select or db_query may suffice as a more lightweight solution.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I suggest is loading the user objects with [entity_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/entity_load/7), or [user_load_multiple()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_load_multiple/7) using the array returned from `$users_query->execute()`. That is the only method that always work.
On Drupal, entity fields can be stored on a different database engine, or on a Mongodb database; directly querying the database could not work, similarly to directly querying the database instead of using [cache_get()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!cache.inc/function/cache_get/7), or [cache_set()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!cache.inc/function/cache_set/7).